# How to check all checkboxes on one field? using JS

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have one field that has 5-6 checkboxes (and will increased more in the future), this field name email_notification, here's the code that i find on google to automatic check all the check boxes on event Form - On Load.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.checked = true;
});
```

When I run the code, it will auto check all my checkboxes on field email_notification, it also check all checkboxes on other field. I just want only one field to automatically check all the checkboxes. Is there any clue to change the syntax? Thank you for helping.

I'm not familiar with Javascript, and I've been googling about this on one week but didn't find any clue.

Comment: The querySelectorAll is acting as intended. Please post your html; This will allow practical suggestions to limit the query selection to a single field.

Comment: I don't use any html codes. Just that code. Field type is check box, field name is email_notification

Comment: If there was no HTML, there would be no checkboxes for your JavaScript to work with.

Comment: I'm using web development tool (Scriptcase), so the tools to generate check box is there. I just need to change the field to checkbox (manually, not with code), that's why there's no html code. I just put the javascript code on javascript code area

Comment: @Nanda add the snapshot of field in question where you are adding check to

Comment: You might have gotten a Scriptcase-specific answer (I am not familiar with Scriptcase), but you can always access the HTML by using your browser's developer tools and its Inspect Element option.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your answer . I think it might help you to solve your question.**

```
<p>Select your favorite colors:</p>
<label for="c1"> <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red" id="c1">Red</label>
<label for="c2"><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green" id="c2"> Green</label>
<label for="c3"><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue" id="c3">Blue</label>
<p>
<button id="button2">check/uncheck all</button>

<script>
    // check function
    function check(checked = true){
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="color"]');
        checkboxes.forEach(checkbox =>{
            checkbox.checked = checked;
        })
    }

    // check all checkboxes
    function checkAll(){
        check();
        this.onclick = uncheckAll;
    }

    // uncheck all
    function uncheckAll(){
        check(false);
        this.onclick = checkAll;
    }

    const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
    button2.onclick = checkAll;
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I was looking for the code that when I enter the form, the check box are all already checked (that's why I'm using Form - On Load), not check it with button, and I only want one field that can check all it check boxes, so other field that has check box too, it won't be checked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using web development tool (Scriptcase).

Use `sc_form` object to interact with the form and its elements. If you want to select all checkboxes within a specific field, you can use the `sc_form.getField` method to get the field, and then use the `getValues` method to get all the checkboxes within that field.

Example;

```
var field = sc_form.getField('email_notification');
var checkboxes = field.getValues();
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
   checkbox.checked = true;
});
```

`sc_form.getField('email_notification')` gets the field with the name **email_notification**. `field.getValues()` gets all the checkboxes within that field. The forEach loop then checks all the checkboxes.

Since you're running this after the form has been loaded, make sure it's inside the function like;

```
sc_form.onLoad = function() {
   var field = sc_form.getField('email_notification');
   var checkboxes = field.getValues();
   checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
       checkbox.checked = true;
   });
};
```